# how do I implement functionality similar to linux /proc/version in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, linux

I have an C++ program that runs on an embedded system. When the client encounters a problem he sends me a log file. And it would be great to see exactly when the binary was build in the log. So, currently I use this simple but very ineffective method:

...

```
const std::string APP_BUILD = "2012.01.17.18:28";

int main()
{
     std::cout << "Was built: " << APP_BUILT << std::endl;
}
```

What I would like to do is to set APP_BUILD automatically during build. I know that Linux has /proc/version variable which can be read to determine build time. My reads

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.38-13-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) ) #53-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 28 19:33:45 UTC 2011
```

Can this be done? (I'm building my app in Linux).

Comment: Check the GCC [pre-defined macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), some data you want is found there.

Comment: If you are using some version control system (and you should), you probably also want to embed some string uniquely identifying the particular version.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Mercurial. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros. These standard macros are available in both C and C++.

See, for example, the [`gcc` manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about it.